# Allow users to add nodal points of a region in space and the region can be color of user's choice.

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am new to google developer and I would like to implement poly lines with nodal points. I have read a lot about it on the google developer website but I couldn't figure it out. Similar to [this website](http://www.doogal.co.uk/polylines.php) but with google markers dropped when clicked if possible. Anyway if anyone can help me out. Will be really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can always follow google map api documentation here:
[Google Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation)
To let user choose the color you can get the color either by HTML5 combobox and or javascript input.